Process is started again after swiping off the task list
I have an Android app and when I swipe it off the task list to close it down, the process first ends and then shortly after it is started again? I checked but the onCreate method of Application is actually not being called at all in this restart so I'm not sure what process could be restarted here? Is there a way to profile that?
This is what I see in logcat:
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (7622) for package com.myapp ----------------------------
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (8870) for package com.myapp ----------------------------

